# How to inject jersey filter without adding it web.xml

Tags: filter, jersey

I dont know if this is possible or not but I have created the Jersey Filter for logging extending the logging filter and I added

```
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
<param-value>com.chegg.commons.web.logging.WebRequestLogger</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
<param-value>com.chegg.commons.web.logging.WebRequestLogger</param-value>
</init-param>
```

in my web.xml and every thing works fine. I want to take it at one more level. Can servlet container call the filter without the entry in web.xml by any annotation on the top of my logging class. Something like @Aspect. I dont want to use @Aspect as it is not a filter.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to modify web.xml? You could use something like Guice servlet (http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule ) but you'd have to modify web.xml to set that up. Then you could control your filters with Java code...

Comment: I am writing common logging functionality which can be used by others. I dont want to tell my clients that "hey in order to use logging, you have to follow certains steps". I am looking of better solution if exists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can always use `@Provider` annotation to annotate your `CustomFilterClasses` and just register these manually or let jersey scan your filters automatically.

for instance:

```
package com.test.poc.filters;
@Provider
public class CustomFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{
 @Override
 public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext){
  //filter logic..
 }
}
```

is one filter which we want to be auto discovered by jersey at runtime so for this we can easily specify one class which extends ResourceConfig

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class CustomResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig{
 public CustomResourceConfig(){
  super();
  packages("com.test.poc.filters;com.test.poc.restservices;com.test.poc.providers");
  //ragister any other classes like
  //register(JacksonFeature.class);
 }
}
```

This will automatically scan for all the classes annotated with `@Provider` or `@Path` in the specified packages